# Multiple Occurrences of same String to List

Tags: python, regex

I have a subprocess command

`temp = subprocess.check_output(cmd)`

This returns a **single string**

The string will contain data, for **every record which has a license**

For Instance,

If there is currently only one record with a license : the string will look like:

```
b'Setting license file path to 5053@100.113.111.61\r\n\r\n\t------------------------\r\n\r\n\tredgiant license usage status on 100.113.248.61 (port 55952)\r\n\r\n\tmagicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle650 1/0 at 02/29 09:51  (handle: 62)\r\n\r\n'
```

If there are two records with a license, it will look like:

```
b'Setting license file path to 5053@100.113.111.61\r\n\r\n\t--------------------
----\r\n\r\n\tredgiant license usage status on 100.113.111.61 (port 55952)\r\n\r
\n\tmagicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle650 1/0 at 02/29 11:42  (handle:
 68)\r\n\tmagicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle647 1/0 at 02/29 11:46  (h
andle: 8d)\r\n\r\n'
```

and so on and so forth as the number grows.

I am trying to extract the `magicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle647 1/0 at 02/29 11:46` portion, as many times as it occurs into a list.

For each occurrence, there should be one item in the list.

Currently I am using

```
def do_work():
    regex= re.compile("magicbulletlooks(.*\))")
    t = subprocess.check_output(my_cmd)
    return re.findall(regex,str(t))
```

However, this only returns me a list of 1 value, which has the complete string from beginning to end and does not store the individual occurrences.

Basically the Goal I am trying to reach is using regex, to create a list of:

```
['magicbulletlooks v999.9 administrator@nynle647 1/0 at 2/29 11:46',
  'magicbulletlooks v999.9 administrator@nynle650 1/0 at 2/29 11:42'
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a fix to your pattern, here is what I could came up with:

```
>>> re.findall('magicbulletlooks.*\d+', s)
['magicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle650 1/0 at 02/29 11:42', 'magicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle647 1/0 at 02/29 11:46']
```

Now in your function:

```
def do_work():
    pat = re.compile('magicbulletlooks.*\d+')
    t = subprocess.check_output(my_cmd)
    return pat.findall(str(t))
```

**EDIT:**
Quoting from docs:

> `subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False,
>   universal_newlines=False, timeout=None)` 
>   Run command with arguments and return its output.
>
> ...
>
> This is equivalent to:
>
> **By default, this function will return the data as encoded bytes. The
>   actual encoding of the output data may depend on the command being
>   invoked, so the decoding to text will often need to be handled at the
>   application level.**
>
> **This behaviour may be overridden by setting universal_newlines to True
>   as described above in Frequently Used Arguments.**

So you have here couple of options:

1 - set `universal_newline` flag to `True` as:

```
t = subprocess.check_output(my_cmd, universal_flag=True)
pat = re.compile('magicbulletlooks.*\d+')
return pat.findall(t)
```

2 - Specify the pattern in the `re` expression as a `binary-like` object:

```
pat = re.compile(b'magicbulletlooks.*\d+')
t = subprocess.check_output(my_cmd)
return pat.findall(t)
```

3 - Decode the `binary-like` object into an `utf-8` (more preferable if dealing with Python3) or `ascii` string:

```
>>> t = subprocess.check_output(my_cmd)
>>>
>>> re.findall('magicbulletlooks.*\d+', t.decode('utf-8'))
['magicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle650 1/0 at 02/29 11:42', 'magicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle647 1/0 at 02/29 11:46']
>>>
>>> re.findall('magicbulletlooks.*\d+', t.decode('ascii'))
['magicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle650 1/0 at 02/29 11:42', 'magicbulletlooks v999.9: administrator@nynle647 1/0 at 02/29 11:46']
```

Comment: it is still coming in 1 liner for me

Comment: I think that's because you are getting the output from `subprocess.check_output` as `byte-like` object, try with this expression then:
`pat = re.compile(b'magicbulletlooks.*\d+')`
Notice the `b` before `magicbulletlooks`...

Comment: That did it, Thanks mate

Comment: @Busturdust .. Glad to be of help :) .. Check the updated answer...I've added couple options for you as well.